# I want to create a postgres stored procedure or function that deletes data from 2 tables where data is older than 30 days

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE FUNCTION purge_data(integer) RETURNS int
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
   row_count int;
Begin
DELETE FROM table_a using table_b
 WHERE  table_a.session_id in (select table_b.id from table_b where cast (started as date) < current_date - ($1::text || '' days'')::interval);
IF found then 
   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_count = ROW_COUNT;
   RAISE NOTICE 'DELETED % row(s) FROM table_a', row_count;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
```

I want to return the number of rows deleted from both tables.  The number of days could change, maybe 30 60 90

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you feel like you need to improve your question, consider reading [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) on SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Forgive me if I am oversimplifying your question. But wouldn't a `DELETE` with a `RETURNING` suffice?

Data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (id INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (generate_series(1,10));
```

Query

```
WITH j AS (
  DELETE FROM t WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 4
  RETURNING *
) SELECT count(*) FROM j;

 count 
-------
     4
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b6c54e8a0679df50e8d7fb944fec349)

If you must have it inside a PL/pgSQL function ..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION purge_data(integer) RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE row_count INT;
BEGIN
  WITH j AS (
    DELETE FROM t WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND $1
    RETURNING *
) SELECT count(*) FROM j INTO row_count;
  RETURN row_count;
END;
$$;


SELECT purge_data(4);

 purge_data 
------------
      4
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9b738a5bf5c8fe5a3c1a8e090cc1743c)